# Notify slack everytime someone runs a terraform file

Tags: terraform, slack, slack-api, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to figure out to notify a slack channel everytime someone does a

```
terraform apply
```

I have gone through https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-notify-slack ,  but this specifically talks about cloud watch alerts. I am thinking of something simple where i can just send something like a notification to slack via calling a webhook at the end of a successful terraform apply.

Can someone point me in some direction , i am okay to develop something to figure it out. Just pointers would also help.

Comment: Why do you want this? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: If you execute Terraform as part of a pipeline then this problem becomes much easier.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR i am trying to just build a small callback plugin which might be able to do notification because right now i don't know who spins what in my team via terraform

Comment: And what stops then removing your callback and running it anyway? If you want to know about things being spun up then you need to have something at your provider know about it such as CloudTrail for AWS but that's a very different question that's probably already been answered.

Answer (score 4):

You could accomplish this through the use of [Terraform's `local-exec` provisioner](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/local-exec.html), which lets you run some executable code locally after a resource has been created:

```
resource "null_resource" "example2" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "curl -X POST 'https://yourchannel.slack.com/api/chat.postMessage?channel=CXXXXXXXX&token=xoxp-#####' -F 'text={\"text\": \"Terraform was applied\"}'"
  }
}
```

Comment: A provisioner only runs one time though. Even in a null_resource it requires triggers to run again. This isn't going to solve the questions problem, but I'm not sure it can be solved with a Terraform resource by itself. In addition. The question asks for notification of successful runs. A provisioner might run even on a failure.

Comment: @BrandonMiller exacty, i need the right result that gets to slack.. who , what , when , success /fail/ rollback

Comment: have you got any solution for this?

Comment: If you have Terraform Cloud, you could use https://www.terraform.io/docs/cloud/workspaces/notifications.html

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved if you're using [Terragrunt](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/).
Terragrunt has a feature for `before` and `after` hooks.

Using this mechanism, we can do something of this sort:

`terragrunt.hcl`:

```
terraform {
  after_hook "Send slack Notification" {
    commands     = ["apply"]
    execute      = ["sh","-c","${get_repo_root()}/scripts/send_slack_notification.sh ${path_relative_to_include()}"]
    run_on_error = false
  }
}
```

`scripts/send_slack_notification.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
folder=$1

WEBHOOK_URL='https://hooks.slack.com/services/<WEBHOOK>'
MESSAGE="Terraform Apply was performed on resource:\n\t$folder\nUser:\n\t$USER"

curl -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data \
    "{'text': '$MESSAGE'}" \
    $WEBHOOK_URL
```